# Getting new Telegram messages from url

Tags: telegram

if I have a Telegram bot and want to get a list of all messages the bot has received, I use this url: `https://api.telegram.org/bot$BOT_TOKEN/getUpdates?offset=0`
(replace `$BOT_TOKEN` with the bot's secret token)

Is there a url I can use to get a similar list of messages that my own telegram account has received? Preferably both from chats and joined channels.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply get user account update via HTTPS API, you need do complex encryption called `MTProtocal`.